# Calling app engine API's in a phonegap application

Tags: java, android, cordova, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am looking to execute an API method in my phonegap application to retrive all the entries from the datastore. I have been testing this on a samsung S4 and can't seem to get any errors or anything in the console and the logs for the datastore indicate that no attempts have been made to retrieve data from the datastore.

I will post my base.js file below which is the function that is suppose the execute the API call.

I have been following this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/clients/js/add_post) created by Google to implement this. The method is for POST rather than GET as according to another tutorial i was following, you must request the data through a post method rather than a get method.

```
var requestData = {};

google.appengine.CMS.client.getCalls = function() {
    gapi.client.call.queryCalls(requestData).execute(function(resp) {
        if (!resp.code) {
        resp.calls = resp.calls || [];
        var result = "";
          for (var i=0;i<resp.calls.length;i++) {
              result = result+ resp.calls[i].callId+ " : " +          resp.calls[i].patientName+ " : " + resp.calls[i].doctor+ " : " + "<br/>" +     resp.calls[i].address1+ " : " + resp.calls[i].address2+ " : " + resp.calls[i].address3+ " : " + "<br/>" + resp.calls[i].postCode + " : " + resp.calls[i].patientLocation+ " : " + resp.calls[i].symptoms+ " : " + "<br/>" + resp.calls[i].contactNumber+ " : " + resp.calls[i].callDateTime+ " : " + resp.calls[i].currentStatus+ "<br/>";
        }
        return result;
        google.appengine.CMS.client.print(resp);
    }
});
};


/**
 * Enables the button callbacks in the UI.
 */
google.appengine.CMS.client.enableButtons = function() {
    var ListCalls = document.querySelector('#listCalls');
    ListCalls.addEventListener('click', google.appengine.CMS.client.getCalls);
};

/**
 * Initializes the application.
 * @param {string} apiRoot Root of the API's path.
 */
var apiRoot = 'generic root';
google.appengine.CMS.client.init = function(apiRoot) {
    // Loads the OAuth and helloworld APIs asynchronously, and triggers login
    // when they have completed.
var apisToLoad;
var callback = function() {
    if (--apisToLoad == 0) {
        google.appengine.CMS.client.enableButtons();
    }
};

apisToLoad = 1; // must match number of calls to gapi.client.load()
gapi.client.load('call', 'v1', callback, apiRoot);
};
```

Comment: The tutorial is for a web client that talks to an App Engine backend via endpoints, but this just looks like a copypaste of some client code from it. You can't access the Datastore directly from client JS without a backend. Going through the whole tutorial first might help.

Comment: I already have the backend set up @Adam. I have set up the Endpoints and they are working for a web app that i have set up to log calls. The Api at the bottom is one that i have created and the "queryCalls" method that is called via `gapi.client.call.queryCalls` is a method in my backend that has been tested via the API explorer and it works fine, but when i call it here it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a packaged phonegapp app, a webview that show  localhost, you need:

- authorize the client id for localhost origin as shown here [1]
- use an absolute reference to the endpoint instead use the window.location.host as shown here [2]
- or follow this part [3]

I suggest you to use a phonegap app that point directly pages on *.appspot.com instead of copy that on the app:

- update the app without the users interaction
- better development because you can test the app outside phonegap
- switch appengine versions and automatically all users are up-to-date

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/backend/setup#creating_an_app_engine_app_for_deployment

[2] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/clients/js/client_ui

instead of

```
<script>
        function init() {
            google.appengine.samples.hello.init('//' + window.location.host + '/_ah/api');
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
```

use

```
<script>
        function init() {
            google.appengine.samples.hello.init('https://youappid.appspot.com/_ah/api');
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
```

[3] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js

Comment: The is very helpful, thank you @aqquadro. I will implement this now and then comeback and let you know how it goes once it is implemented

Comment: got it working @aqquadro. The second part of the tutorial with setting up the namespace is kind of misleading as it leads you to believe that you are importing types with the goo.appengine.sample call, whereas that doesn't really do much. I would reccoment everyone else just to follow the first two points on this link to get it working. Again, thank you very much for the help and all the best in the future.